# For-In loop in Javascript (Node.js) unexpectedly iterates through array indexes instead of elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I have a Node.js script that reads and parses the content of a JSON file and iterates through the elements of its root array; when I try to inspect the objects of such iteration I am faced with some unexpected result; the object being iterated seems to be the index of the element being iterated.
Here is the script:

```
if (process.argv.length != 3) {
    console.log("Usage: node chooseAdAmongAds.js /path/to/ads.json");
    process.exit(9);
}

fs = require("fs");
var content = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], "utf8")

var ads = JSON.parse(content);
for (ad in ads) {
    console.log(ad);
}
```

The JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "impressions": 131, 
        "ID": 514, 
        "investment": 2
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 880, 
        "ID": 451, 
        "investment": 5
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 135, 
        "ID": 198, 
        "investment": 9
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 744, 
        "ID": 262, 
        "investment": 8
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 234, 
        "ID": 954, 
        "investment": 19
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 673, 
        "ID": 274, 
        "investment": 12
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 442, 
        "ID": 734, 
        "investment": 6
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 453, 
        "ID": 982, 
        "investment": 5
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 55, 
        "ID": 275, 
        "investment": 5
    }, 
    {
        "impressions": 628, 
        "ID": 524, 
        "investment": 1
    }
]
```

And the console output:

```
iMac-di-Michele:Node.js michele$ node chooseAdAmongAds.js example.json 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
iMac-di-Michele:Node.js michele$
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for...in` loops over enumerable properties of an Object and arrays are objects.  [You should not use `for...in` for array iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Instead, use Array constructs for iteration such as `.forEach`, or just use a `for` loop and access the array element by its index.

```
ads.forEach(function (ad) {
    console.log(ad)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just outputting the index. Try

```js
console.log(ads[ad]);
```